# Razor Syntax / WebMatrix - C# Question

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, razor, webmatrix

In Windows Forms I can create a class file called 'Authentication.cs' with the following code:

```
public class Authentication
{
    public string Name;

    internal bool Authenticate()
    {
        bool i = false;
        if (Name == "Jason")
        {
            i = true;

        }
        return i;
    }
}
```

In WebMatrix, I can insert a new Class file, called 'Authentication.cs', and insert the above code.

And in my default.cshtml file, I do this:

```
<body>
   @{
      Authentication auth = new Authentication();
      if(auth.Authenticated("jasonp"))
      {
         <p>@auth.Authenticated("jasonp");</p>
      }
   }
</body>
```

But it won't work! It works for the WinForms desktop app, but not in WebMatrix. I don't know why it's not working. The error message is:

> "The namespace Authenticate does not
>   exist. Are you sure you have
>   referenced assemblies etc?"

So, then at the top of my default.cshtml file I tried this:

```
@using Authentication.cs;
```

Which led to the exact same error!

There's no documentation that I can find anywhere that tells you how to "include" a class file into your WebMatrix pages.

Any help is appreciated,

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just drop the cs file in you App_Code directory

then do something like this

```
    @{
      Authentication auth = new Authentication();
      if(auth.Authenticated("jasonp"))
      {
         <p>@auth.Authenticated("jasonp");</p>
      }
   }
```

No need to add a using.

Additionally if you wanted to use a .dll then you would need the using

```
@using NameSpace.Authenication

@{
    Authenticated auth = new Authenicated();

 }

 @if(@auth.Authenticated("jasonp"))
 {
    <p>@auth.Authenticated("jasonp")</p>
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You import a namespace, not a file. So; what **namespace** is `Authentication` in? For example:

@using My.Utils.Authentication.cs;

Also - you want to drop the `;` in the razor call:

```
<p>@auth.Authenticated("jasonp")</p>
```

You can also provide the fully qualified name in the code:

```
   @{
      var auth = new My.Utils.Authentication();
      if(auth.Authenticated("jasonp"))
      {
         <p>@auth.Authenticated("jasonp")</p>
      }
   }
```

(aside: are you intentionally calling the same method twice with the same values?)

Comment: Yeps, the two method calls are intentional. This isn't for a customer or anything, this is just for learning/etc. I don't have a namespace, when a new Class File is created in WebMatrix, there's no namespace (like there is in winforms/desktop apps). But it keeps referring to it as if it did have one. @Marc, where'd you get the "My.Utils" from? Am I supposed to include these class files in a folder named My.Utils? Sorry if this is really nooby but I'm completely lost.

Comment: @Lucifer I simply invented it. Does WebMatrix *let* you use a namespace?

Comment: Nope; Not as far as I can see.

Answer (score 0):

Create a file named linkRef.cs
code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;


public class linkRef
{
   public  linkRef() {
        //
        // TODO: Add constructor logic here   
    //
   }
}
```

Put it in a folder App_code then by dot net 2012 publish to bin then upload bin folder

Comment: create App_Code folder put cs file to this folder convert App_Code to dll in bin folder then upload bin folder (by visual studio 2012/publish web site)